# Delegate `System.Func<bool>' does not take `1' arguments

Tags: c#, .net

when user enter password from login activity  sending it to login service 
and waiting for the boolean response in login service.but its giving above syntax error(I mentioned it in code ) can any one solve my problem.
i've to wait until the service response  comes to my login activity

1.Login Interface

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace RetailAppShared
{
    public interface ILoginServices
    {
        bool AuthenticateUser (string passcode, Func<bool> function);
    }
}
```

2.Login service

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using RestSharp;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace RetailAppShared
{
    public class LoginServices : ILoginServices
    {               
        public bool AuthenticateUser (string passcode, Func<bool> function)
        {

            try {
                RestClient _client = new RestClient ("https://www.example.com/app/class");
                var request = new RestRequest ("loginservice", Method.POST) {
                    RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
                };
                var obj = new login ();
                obj.passcode = passcode;

                request.AddJsonBody (obj);
                request.AddHeader ("Content-type", "application/json");
                _client.ExecuteAsync (request, response => {
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (response.Content)) {
                            var objlog = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginModel> (response.Content);
                            flag = objlog.result.state == 1 ? true : false;

                            function (true);//error
                        } else
                            flag = false;                            
                    }

                });
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Debug.WriteLine (@" ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
            }               
        }    

    }

    class login
    {
        public string passcode { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

3.login activity

```
Login.Click += async (object sender, EventArgs e) => {

    progress = ProgressDialog.Show (this, "", "Connecting...");

    var isLoginSuccessful = loginAuthenticator.AuthenticateUser                
    (password.Text, (value) => {
        Console.WriteLine (value);
    });//error

    if (progress != null) {
        progress.Dismiss ();
        progress = null;
    }

    if (isLoginSuccessful) {                
        StartActivity (typeof(Ledger_HomeActivity));
        this.Finish ();
    } else {
       Toast.MakeText (this, "Invalid Login credentials! try    again", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
    }
};
```

Comment: A `Func<bool>` is like a method that returns a `bool` but has no parameters.  You should call it like `bool result = function();`.  If instead you want to pass a `bool` in and have no return values then you should use `Action<bool>` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error appears at this line

```
var isLoginSuccessful = loginAuthenticator.AuthenticateUser (password.Text, (value) => { Console.WriteLine (value); }):
```

A `Func<bool>` returns a boolean without expecting anything. What you want instead is an `Action<bool>` that expects a boolean but returns `void`:

```
public bool AuthenticateUser (string passcode, Action<bool> function)
{
    function(true);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `function` represents a callback method that *you* call with the value of `true` or `false`, and that does not return any value back to you. In this case you should [`Action<bool>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead of `Func<bool>`, because `Func<bool>` does the opposite - it takes no parameters, and returns a `bool` value back to you.